# Let $\beta$ be a nonzero element of $GF(q^m)$. Let e be the smallest non-negative integer such that $\beta^{q^e}=\beta$. Prove that $e $ divides $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $\beta$ be a nonzero element of $GF(q^m)$. Let $e$ be the smallest non-negative integer such that $\beta^{q^e}=\beta$. Prove that $e $ divides $m$.

Can you give me a hint on where to start this proof?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in your question you should say *positive integer*, rather than *non-negative integer*, as otherwise $e=0$. With the corrected question:

$GF(q^m)$ is a vector space over the smallest subfield containing $\beta$.

The size of the smallest subfield containing $\beta$ is $q^e$ as:

1. $\mathbb{F}_q[\beta]$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $GF({q^e})$, as $GF({q^e})$ is a splitting field for the polynomial $x^{q^e-1}-1$, which $\beta$ satisfies.
2. $\mathbb{F}_q[\beta]$ cannot be a proper subfield of $GF({q^e})$ of size $q^r$, as then $\beta^{q^r}=\beta$ for some $0<r<e$.

The size of a vector space of dimension $d$ over a field of size $q^e$ is $(q^e)^d=q^{ed}$.

We conclude $q^m=q^{ed}$, so $m=ed$ as required.

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

To prove this for $q=2$, we can proceed as,
We know that,
$$\beta^{{2^m}-1}=1$$
$$\implies \beta^{2^m}=\beta$$
Let $m = n\cdot e+r$, such that,
$$\beta^{2^{n\cdot e+r}}=\beta$$
$$(({({\beta^{2^e}})^{2^e}})^{2^e}\cdots)^{2^r}=\beta$$
$$\implies \beta^{2^r}=\beta$$
As $r < e$ and e is the smallest integer to satisfy $\beta^{2^e}=\beta$ $$\implies r=0$$
Hence,
$$m=n\cdot e$$
which is to say that $e$ divides $m$.

Comment: Perfect - except again, to deduce $r=0$ you need *smallest positive integer* in the line above.  Of course you can just replace $2$ with $q$.  As you now have an answer, I will change my hint to an answer.